# How to use **row()** function with **if()** statement in Excel-2010 to return the row number if value is *true*

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row, excel-2010

how to use **row()** function with **if()** statement in Excel-2010 to return the row number if value is *true*.
If there is some other way with which I can do the same job it'll be appreciated too.
The Job is: I have a range of data in a single column with multiple rows and the condition is "if the value of data is greater than 50" than I have to print all the desired data in another column with each data in a separate row.

If this is possible with the **row()** and **if()** function, it's ok, any other methods' are also invited.

Comment: Can you please provide the desired output as an example?

Comment: To me it sounds like you don't need the row function. Can you show some sample data and a screenshot with desired output?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a filter and then copy/paste.

Comment: 'Aggregate()` formula will serve your purpose.

Comment: Thank You guyz, the problem is Solved with the Help of the formula given by Roman Voronov. I need another Help though...
The problem is when I am using the **Multiple Cell Array Formula**, I have to select a minimum amount of cells and then apply the formula by pressing (Ctrl+Shift+Enter), but this is a manual method.
By any means can I make that automatic, i.e. I write the formula and the output result takes place serially in each cell of a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your task right, but let's try. Let's imagine you have some random numbers in cells `A2:A20`. You can select cells `C2:C20` and input a ***multiple cell array formula*** by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` on Windows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$20,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$20>50,ROW($A$2:$A$20),"-"),ROW()-ROW($C$1))-ROW($A$1)),"")
```

Which will check, if those numbers are higher then 50 and print only relevant ones. Range, where you enter this formula MUST be at least equal in size to the range you "filter".

**UPD: So, how does it work?**

**Stage 1** - filtering:

```
$A$2:$A$20>50
```

In array formula, this code will turn your values into ordered (which is important) array of **True**'s and **False**'s according to >50 checks. For example, if you have a table with values `{55,10,40,51,49,89}` they will turn into `{True,False,False,True,False,True}`

**Stage 2** - value separation & position

```
IF( [Stage 1] ,ROW($A$2:$A$20),"-")
```

This **IF** statement, based on True/False check, returns either POSITION of an element or string value "-". Position relates to a sheet, not to the values - it will be important later. So, now we deal with the array of positions for elements who passed our check and some string values for all others.

**Stage 3** - reorder positions

```
SMALL( [Stage 2] ,ROW()-ROW($C$1))-ROW($A$1)
```

The **SMALL** function helps us to reorder positions we get from STAGE 3. So we turn ordered array like `{2,"-","-",5,"-",7}` into `{2,5,7,"#NUM!","#NUM!","#NUM!"}`. Error tells us that we tryed to perform some numeric action with the string. It's exactly what we needed to sort irrelevant values out. The returned value is `ROW()-ROW($C$1)` and by this subtraction, I define which number of the array from the minimum to return for each row. Last subtraction `-ROW($A$1)` turns sheet related positions `{2,5,7,"#NUM!","#NUM!","#NUM!"}` into your table related positions `{1,4,6,"#NUM!","#NUM!","#NUM!"}`

**Stage 4** - return initial values

```
INDEX($A$2:$A$20, [Stage 3] )
```

This is the most simple part in my opinion. So, we have the array of the table related positions. Now we can turn it into actual values with the **INDEX** function. We tell that function what table to look at and which rows values to return. So our in memory array `{1,4,6,"#NUM!","#NUM!","#NUM!"}` turns into something like this `{55,51,89,"#NUM!","#NUM!","#NUM!"}`. Which is already a result we want. Since we use a ***multiple cell array formula*** - all values will spread among rows.

**Stage 5** - esthetic

```
=IFERROR( [Stage 4] ,"")
```

Just makes error values invisible. It's an optional step, I just like when reports are smooth and shiny.

Comment: It worked... :D
Now If u can Explain to me, what each of these Formulae does step by step for the process to take place.
It would be Helpful for me :)

Comment: @gori_1996 sure, I'll add notes to the original post soon.

Comment: @gori_1996 done. Please check if my explanation is understandable. I'm ready to add more if something looks unclear.

Comment: Thank You very much Roman Voronov for your Help and explanation. It did Help me but now I am stuck with another one. The problem is when I am using the **Multiple Cell Array Formula**, I have to select a minimum amount of cells and then apply the formula by pressing (Ctrl+Shift+Enter), but this is a manual method. By any means can I make that automatic, i.e. I write the formula and the output result takes place serially in each cell of a column.